Snowflake "like" query
I am using like query inside snowflake stored procedure. Used jsonString as parameter. Parsed the JsonString and assigned the value in local variable which declared inside stored procedure.
I used like query like below
select * 
from tableName 
where columnName like variablename

It returns all the data - like the search is not working.
Then I used this
select * 
from tableName 
where columnName like :variablename

It says

Bind variable not set

But I declared the variable name.
In snowflake how to use like query inside stored procedure.

You need to use dynamic SQL and use  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE check the following sample.
create or replace  table temp as  (with data as (select * from values ('Test'),('Best'),('Rest'), ('Lost and found')) select * from data);

select * from temp;
 
DECLARE
  res RESULTSET;
  col_name VARCHAR;
  select_statement VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  col_name := 'COLUMN1';
  select_statement := 'SELECT ' || col_name || ' FROM temp where COLUMN1 Like ' || '''' || 'Tes%' || '''';
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;

